# Complex varieties with non-torsion homotopy groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, homotopy-theory

Is there some kind of classification of (connected) smooth complex varieties such that every homotopy group of the manifold of complex points is torsion-free? Any reference on this topic will be most welcome.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "affine space"?

Comment: Perhaps what is meant is a manifold where the transition maps are affine? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold

Comment: Surely you need more hypotheses to make progress?  For example, any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an affine manifold (all transition maps are the identity).

Comment: @JohnPardon Sorry, meant to write affine scheme

Comment: In characteristic $p$, $\pi_q = 0$ for $q>1$ and $\pi_1$ has no $p$-torsion, but that's of course very different from char. $0$ or the complex topology...

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Could you suggest some reference which deals with examples of non-torsion homotopy groups in the complex topology.

Comment: There are many interesting $K(\pi, 1)$ examples, e.g. certain complements of hyperplane arrangements. I don't know examples with nontrivial torsion-free higher homotopy groups.

Comment: What do you mean by homotopy group? The ordinary homotopy groups of the complex points?

Comment: @SeanTilson Yes. Consider the scheme as a complex manifold (assuming non-singularity).

Comment: A smooth complex variety has the homotopy type of a finite CW complex. So I doubt you'll find *any* examples with all homotopy groups torsion free.

Comment: Further to Donu Arapura's comment, perhaps David Chataur's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207448/simply-connected-cw-complex-with-only-finitely-many-nontrivial-homotopy-and-homo can be used to show that the only examples are $K(\pi,1)$'s as mentioned by Piotr Achinger.

Comment: @MarkGrant Are curves complements of hyperplane arrangements? Because they are all $K(\pi, 1)$ So are products, and fiber products thereof, though I am not sure if there is a classification of which of the latter are algebraic...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following Mark Grant's comment, referencing David Chataur's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207448/simply-connected-cw-complex-with-only-finitely-many-nontrivial-homotopy-and-homo): McGibbon and Neisendorfer proved that a finite-dimensional 1-connected space with any nonzero reduced homology has infinitely many homotopy groups with torsion. In particular, this applies to the universal cover $\tilde{X}$ of the space $X$ we care about. So $\tilde{X}$ must be acyclic (and is simply-connected), and is thus contractible by Hurewicz's theorem. Therefore $X$ is aspherical.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is likely to be a bit messy, since every projective curve is a $K(\pi, 1),$ and so are cartesian products and (iterated) fibrations of such (classifying which of these are algebraic is, presumably, still open, even for surface bundles over surfaces). I assume, in my ignorance, that complements of hyperplane arrangements are *not* of this form, which makes me think that the question is hopeless.